# Resetting wait cursor in browser with Content-Disposition:attachment

Tags: javascript, content-disposition, mouse-cursor

The following code works nicely:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';
    }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
</script>
```

When the response returns an attachment, though (a PDF from the ReportViewer control, for instance):

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=some.pdf")
```

EndRequest() never fires and the "progress" cursor is not reset.
A Javascript call, e.g.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "close", 
   "parent.EndRequest(...);", true);
```

would do the trick, but is not possible because of the content disposition. 
Can you think of a way to do this correctly - show a wait cursor while a PDF is rendered, and return to the normal cursor when the PDF is displayed? I am assuming a C# context here, but the problem is not language- or platform-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the EndRequest function is not being fired.  Have you tried to see if the pageLoading and the pageLoaded events are firing?

I have a feeling these events are not firing because there is nothing sent back to the page (the attachment doesn't reach the page the same way an inline document does).

I would move the file download into an iframe.  Here is an example of how to do that:

```
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';

    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = 'your pdf file';
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe); 
}
```

Then you can access the onload event of the iframe.

**EDIT:**

Further searching led me to [this page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AjaxFileDownload).  It seems to do all that you're looking to do.

Comment: pageLoaded is not fired either, and this makes sense in a way, because the response does not really make it back to the browser's page context. Nothing is loaded that replaces the current page.

Comment: See modified answer.  Includes more details.

Comment: I'm glad we found a solution.  Good luck with the rest of your project.